# What are the most cool and modern programming areas nowadays?

Tags: programming-languages

In preparation for a blog post about programming, I'm gathering ideas around areas of programming and software development that are actual, new, fresh, cool, interesting and are potentially profitable in the near future.

I've gathered these ideas:

- apps for Facebook and Twitter
- apps for other API based websites (social apps)
- cell phones, Pocket PC applications
- robots and automation
- web tool applications for other programmers
- multilingual websites and web tools

Do you know other issues/trends that can be added to this list?

Comment: OP, you got cash to invest? ;P

Comment: Not, but I would like to share with my readers some ideas what areas are worth investigating as a programmer

Comment: Those all sound like last year's business ideas to me.

Comment: @Nosredna, Than suggests yours

Comment: I'll let you know in another year after I see what happens. :-)

Comment: @Nosrednia, It will be too late

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is my top 10 list of what is ***funky***, ***cool***, ***happening*** and ***grooooovy***:

1. In at 1, Concurrency, scalability and distributed data implementations
2. In at 2, Programming Languages and Meta-Object structures
3. In at 3, Image analysis and automated environment interpretation
4. In at 4, AI and NLP combinations in Search technologies
5. In at 5, Self-replicating automata and swarm intelligence
6. In at 6, Human/Machine hardware interfaces (wetware)
7. In at 7, Nano-robotics in medicine
8. In at 8, Medical/Life Simulation (think simulating a virus that attacks cancer)
9. In at 9, Real-time Raytraced graphics
10. In at 10, Automated Social Interaction/experimentation using online communities

I feel it might be balanced to add a few ***Empty hype*** items that have potential, but so far are pretty lame/boring from a technical perspective ... but with some thought could get interesting:

1. Location Based Services
2. <strike>Google Wave ... isn't this just very rich, relational email?</strike> I take this back, I watched the developer video thingy. Now i'm hyped :P
3. Wikis ... Blank canvas, not much going on. How dry is wikipedia ;P
4. Payment/virtual currency. Too much freeconomy going on online.
5. Secondlife/MM-style games - Interesting tech, no juice
6. Flash, Silverlight, JavaFX - A single open solution might be nice.
7. Google Chrome OS - Doing away with X11! Sounds like Microsoft's embrace-extend-extinguish game plan to me

Note: Facebook, Google and Twitter do not appear in the list. They are API

Comment: Are you sure Google Chrome OS is going to do away with X11? They say they are going to make a a "new windowing system", but I sort of suspect that's just marketing-speak for writing a new window manager for X11, which is actually pretty trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Cloud computing and apps that utilize it effectively.

Comment: Not really that new. Old stuff, new packaging.

Comment: Yes, but it does fall into cool, interesting, and an area where ally of money will be made in the future.

Comment: Old IBM systems are cool and interesting too.

Comment: Aiden, you have a viable list and I agree with it having the most votes on this question, but if you don't think that things like Amazon EC2 and the future applications of it aren't truly cool, interesting, and relevant to the future of computing then I think you may be in denial.  Nothing is a sure thing, and Cloud has it's hang ups (see Mas post), but it is a very promising technology.  Virtualization isn't new either, but it's ease of use, features and capabilities, and the way we use it have changed quite a bit and has put it in the "lime-light" per se over the past couple years.

Comment: I understand what EC2 and others do, and I think in terms of application environments things like GAE are much more interesting than the usual virtualization candidates. What I wont do is get excited about yet-another-abstraction unless it peaks my interest, in the same way I have no interest in the abstractions in the power-grid or water supply. Cloud computing is just plumbing ... I don't care ... unless it does something more than just plumbing.

Comment: There is a difference between the 'future of computing' which to my mind includes computation, algorithms, data-structures, abstraction and so on ... and then alot of tried-and-tested theory being put to work on something as mundane as virtual-machines. I can get excited about cloud computing when it starts to provide the future of computing. Scalability granted, in the myriad of ways it can be obtained, can I do anything more on EC2, Slicehost or GAE than I currently can on my workstation?

Comment: I find the technology in SANs more interesting than the front-end server systems.

Answer (score 4):

Using the tremendous power of GPU for non-graphics-relateted calculations. See nVidia CUDA to get an idea. This is pretty new right now so it's only gathering momentum, but I expect that it will see more widespread use in the coming decade.

Answer (score 2):

Visual programming through tools like [Processing](http://processing.org/), "*an open source programming language and environment for people who want to program images, animation, and interactions."*

Comment: Processing is such a cool language, I just wish they didn't pick a name that's such a terrible pain to google.

Answer (score 2):

Telecommunications area in general.
And particularly environments/programming languages supporting it ([Erlang](http://erlang.org/) for example).

Comment: +1: Breeding ground of MySQL too (not that I like it much)

Answer (score 1):

Technologies supporting cloud computing reliability, security and scalability

Answer (score 1):

**Physical computing / [ubicomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquitous_computing)**, especially [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and similar ways that these concepts can be popularised. (See [this](http://www.urbanhonking.com/ideasfordozens/2009/05/why_the_arduino_matters.html) piece comparing its significance to that of the Altair 8800).

Answer (score 1):

As always, Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

All areas of programming are, or could be interesting. But this doesn't really answer your question :)

Well, [mashups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_(web_application_hybrid)) are cool.

Answer (score 0):

My programming interest in technology are Mashups, Web 2.0, .Net 3.5, parallel programming. However, learning algorithms are also interesting, I'm interested on evolutionary learning such as genetic algorithm and ant colony. I think, modern technologies and learning algorithms would be a good combination.

Answer (score 0):

Metaprogramming is also pretty cool. Code analysis (FxCop, StyleCop, NDepend, ...) and modifying existing assemblies (ILMerge, Mono Linker, ...).

Answer (score 0):

**Mobile device development** such as iPhone, Palm Pre, Android programming seem be reasonably hot at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the most cool and modern
>   programming areas nowadays?

Robotics.